# Does git create extra files

Tags: ruby, git

I have created a project called **zz** and it has a single file called **ruby.rb** in it. I am using git. I have already added ruby.rb to the staging area. Now I have modified the ruby.rb file and using `git status` below is the output.

```
nikhil@pc:/home/rapps/zz$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   ruby.rb
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   ruby.rb~
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Now I see another file **ruby.rb~** even though, I did not created it. Is git creating this file. I have seen tutorials on Internet and I think I have found this on my system only.

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10 using gedit with gmate plug-gins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git does not create these files on my system, but I know gedit has a back-up system. If you disable the backup in gedit's preferences, the files should not be created again.

You can put this into the .gitignore file so git won't commit them:

```
*~
```

Comment: Yes, I have enabled the gedit back-up system. Now I have added the *~ to my .gitignore file too.

Answer (score 4):

That's a temporary file created by some text editors. You may wish to create a [`.gitignore` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) to automatically ignore such files to prevent them from accidentally being added to your repository. You would put

```
*~
```

in your `.gitignore` file to exclude all files ending with a tilde.

Answer (score 1):

No, Git does not create files like ruby.rb~ This is a common method text editor applications do to save backups of the currently edited file.

Answer (score 1):

No, git is not adding this file. It is likely being used as a file buffer or backup by your text editor. If you close your text editor, does the file disappear?

Git won't ever add a file or change the file system of your repository except in the .git directory, which Git knows to treat different.